# Using a rados block device as block device in libvirt qemu

Tags: linux, qemu, ceph

What is the difference between using a rados block device in libvirt qemu with disk type='network' and disk type='block'? The ceph guide tells me to do the following:

```
<disk type='network' device='disk'>
        <source protocol='rbd' name='libvirt-pool/new-libvirt-image'>
                <host name='{monitor-host}' port='6789'/>
        </source>
        <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
</disk>
```

http://ceph.com/docs/master/rbd/libvirt/

But right now I'm just using the rbd directly like:

```
<disk type='block' device='disk'>
  <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' io='native'/>
  <source dev='/dev/rbd/rbd/testvm'/>
  <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x0'/>
</disk>
```

Are there any downsides in using it directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a Linux RBD device you use the Ceph RBD layer indirectly. The Linux device does talk with the Ceph RBD layer. So when using the `type=network protocol=rbd` disk you are removing one indirection layer. Also the RBD (ram) cache is not available with the kernel driver (but the page cache is used). So generally it is a good idea to use the first option.

Comment: That's what I did in the end. There are several advantages in using librbd/qemu directly. Thanks!